# ASP.NET MVC AddJsonpFormatter not recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using VS2013 in a ASP.Net MVC project. I want to add json formatting:

https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp

I already installed the package using package manager console:

```
Install-Package WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp
```

But in global.asax I can't add the code:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.AddJsonpFormatter();
```

I'm getting the following error:

> 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddJsonpFormatter' and no extension method 'AddJsonpFormatter'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Proyectos\laive\laive.trade\CC\Web\Global.asax.cs    18  47  Web

Thank you in advance,
Paul.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following:

using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp;

Comment: This is true if you're using 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I worked out with my WebAPi project,

> Update-Packages

, to make sure it's webapi v2

> Install WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp

Put this in Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
                jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                config.AddJsonpFormatter();
            });
```

Comment: This trick is u have to download code sample from WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp   at Github ;)